# Retornando os valores de um model de forma dinâmica no .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma classe de autenticação que armazena o ID do usuário em uma sessão, que recebe o nome do model correspondente ao usuário atual, como por exemplo: users, admins, clientes.

Exemplo:

```
Authentication.Guard("users").Attempt(user.id)
```

Porém, nesta classe de autenticação há o método `Get()`, que deverá retornar os dados do usuário guardados no banco através do model que recebe como parâmetro o nome da session `guard_name` e o valor da mesma.

```
public <guard_name> Get()
{
    ...

    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        return db.<guard_name>.Where(p => p.id == session)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

O problema é que como o nome da session `guard_name` pode variar entre users, admins e clients, eu preciso de uma forma de retorno mais dinâmica ou de talvez utilizar alguma interface.

Como posso resolver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interfaces podem ser um bom ponto de partida. Implemente uma interface para os três tipos:

```
public class User : IMinhaInterface { ... }
public class Admin : IMinhaInterface { ... }
public class Client : IMinhaInterface { ... }
```

`Get()` ficaria assim:

```
public IMinhaInterface Get<T>()
    where T: class, IMinhaInterface
{
    ...

    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        return db.Set<T>.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == session);
    }
}
```

`Guard` receberia um tipo, e não mais uma `string`.

```
Authentication.Guard(User).Attempt(user.id);
```