# Passando como parâmetro um tipo genérico em um atributo no .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, genéricos

Em uma outra pergunta que fiz [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137637/retornando-os-valores-de-um-model-de-forma-din%C3%A2mica-no-net-mvc/137642#137642) tive a necessidade de modificar a minha classe de autenticação para retornar os valores do model referente ao usuário e ao tipo de usuário autenticado, por exemplo, admins, users, clients, portanto tive que implementar um tipo genérico à chamada, e uma nova interface. Porém em conjunto com a classe de autenticação utilizo um `ActionFilterAttribute` para permitir ou negar o acesso aos actions das *routes*, a declaração é:

```
[Authorized("users")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ...
```

Mas por se tratar de um atributo eu não estou conseguindo implementar um tipo genérico para que eu possa utilizar a classe de autenticação para fazer as verificações necessárias, como no exemplo a seguir, que não funciona, mas é somente para descrever a necessidade:

Declaração:

```
[Authorized<users>]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ...
```

Filtro:

```
public class Authorized : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private T guard;

    public Authorized<T>() where T : class, IAuth
    {
        this.guard = guard;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(Auth.<T>Check())
            ...
    }
}
```

Então tentei iniciar o tipo através de uma string como no primeiro exemplo, a classe do filtro é:

```
public class Authorized : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string guard_name;

    public Authorized(string guard_name)
    {
        this.guard_name = guard_name;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(Auth.Guard(guard_name).Check())
            ...
    }
}
```

Percebam que na execução eu faço a verificação com o método `Check()` que recebe como parâmetro T o retorno do método `Guard()`, que recebe uma string e retorna um tipo.

```
Auth.Guard(string guard_name).Check()
```

O método `Guard` da classe `Auth` fica assim:

```
public static T Guard<T>(string guard_name) where T : class, IAuth
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(guard_name));
}
```

E também não funcionou porque o método `Auth.Guard()` não aceita somente uma string, é necessário que também seja passado como referência um tipo para passar como `T` parâmetro para outros métodos como `Auth.Check()`, porém dentro do filtro `Autorized` eu não tenho como passar esta referência.

Tentei desta forma e também não funciona pois o `T` é inválido:

```
public static T Guard(string guard_name)
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(guard_name));
}
```

Como posso resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar um tipo para seu atributo:

```
[Authorized(typeof(User))]
```

Seu atributo teria que mudar um pouco:

```
public class Authorized : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private Type guardType;

    ...
}
```

A chamada ao método de verificação eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if(Auth.Check(guardType))
        ...
}
```

`Check` deve ter uma assinatura assim:

```
public bool Check(Type tipo) { ... }
```